# Java: Triple Curly Bracing

Tags: java, coding-style, folding

I've been given some code with commenting unlike anything I've come across before:

```
//{{{ Imports
import imports;
//}}}
```

It is the same for each method block,

```
//{{{ above the code block  
//}}} below the code block
```

Also see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folding_editor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick search for *"triple curly" comment* suggests it's "[Emacs folding mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/FoldingMode)".

Or some other code folding marker in any case.

Answer (score 4):

[jEdit](http://www.jedit.org) uses {{{ and }}} to mark "explicit" folds.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Vim uses those triple braces in comments, too.

Tell the one you got the code from, that folding this way is a [bad idea](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-code-folding/). Vim can set fold points at syntactic folding hints, defined in the highlighting file.

Answer (score 1):

It may also be for some code generators. Some generators allow you to edit generated code, and use markers like that so the generator knows where it can regenerate.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it's to emphasize a code block?

*shrugs*